# 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports when start the promethus exporter

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, bitnami

After I install the promethus using helm in kubernetes cluster, the pod shows error like this:

```
0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports.
```

this is the deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-prometheus-1660560589-node-exporter-n7rzg
  generateName: kube-prometheus-1660560589-node-exporter-
  namespace: reddwarf-monitor
  uid: 73986565-ccd8-421c-bcbb-33879437c4f3
  resourceVersion: '71494023'
  creationTimestamp: '2022-08-15T10:51:07Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kube-prometheus-1660560589
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: node-exporter
    controller-revision-hash: 65c69f9b58
    helm.sh/chart: node-exporter-3.0.8
    pod-template-generation: '1'
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: apps/v1
      kind: DaemonSet
      name: kube-prometheus-1660560589-node-exporter
      uid: 921f98b9-ccc9-4e84-b092-585865bca024
      controller: true
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
status:
  phase: Pending
  conditions:
    - type: PodScheduled
      status: 'False'
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-08-15T10:51:07Z'
      reason: Unschedulable
      message: >-
        0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the
        requested pod ports.
  qosClass: BestEffort
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: proc
      hostPath:
        path: /proc
        type: ''
    - name: sys
      hostPath:
        path: /sys
        type: ''
    - name: kube-api-access-9fj8v
      projected:
        sources:
          - serviceAccountToken:
              expirationSeconds: 3607
              path: token
          - configMap:
              name: kube-root-ca.crt
              items:
                - key: ca.crt
                  path: ca.crt
          - downwardAPI:
              items:
                - path: namespace
                  fieldRef:
                    apiVersion: v1
                    fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        defaultMode: 420
  containers:
    - name: node-exporter
      image: docker.io/bitnami/node-exporter:1.3.1-debian-11-r23
      args:
        - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
        - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
        - '--web.listen-address=0.0.0.0:9100'
        - >-
          --collector.filesystem.ignored-fs-types=^(autofs|binfmt_misc|cgroup|configfs|debugfs|devpts|devtmpfs|fusectl|hugetlbfs|mqueue|overlay|proc|procfs|pstore|rpc_pipefs|securityfs|sysfs|tracefs)$
        - >-
          --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(dev|proc|sys|var/lib/docker/.+)($|/)
      ports:
        - name: metrics
          hostPort: 9100
          containerPort: 9100
          protocol: TCP
      resources: {}
      volumeMounts:
        - name: proc
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /host/proc
        - name: sys
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /host/sys
        - name: kube-api-access-9fj8v
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: metrics
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 120
        timeoutSeconds: 5
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 6
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: metrics
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 30
        timeoutSeconds: 5
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 6
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1001
        runAsNonRoot: true
  restartPolicy: Always
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  serviceAccountName: kube-prometheus-1660560589-node-exporter
  serviceAccount: kube-prometheus-1660560589-node-exporter
  hostNetwork: true
  hostPID: true
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1001
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchFields:
              - key: metadata.name
                operator: In
                values:
                  - k8smasterone
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - weight: 1
          podAffinityTerm:
            labelSelector:
              matchLabels:
                app.kubernetes.io/instance: kube-prometheus-1660560589
                app.kubernetes.io/name: node-exporter
            namespaces:
              - reddwarf-monitor
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  tolerations:
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoExecute
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoExecute
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoSchedule
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoSchedule
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoSchedule
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoSchedule
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/network-unavailable
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoSchedule
  priority: 0
  enableServiceLinks: true
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
```

I have checked the host machine and found the port 9100 is free, why still told that no port for this pod? what should I do to avoid this problem? this is the host port 9100 check command:

```
[root@k8smasterone grafana]# lsof -i:9100
[root@k8smasterone grafana]#
```

this is the pod describe info:

```
➜  ~ kubectl describe pod kube-prometheus-1660560589-node-exporter-n7rzg -n reddwarf-monitor
Name:           kube-prometheus-1660560589-node-exporter-n7rzg
Namespace:      reddwarf-monitor
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app.kubernetes.io/instance=kube-prometheus-1660560589
                app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                app.kubernetes.io/name=node-exporter
                controller-revision-hash=65c69f9b58
                helm.sh/chart=node-exporter-3.0.8
                pod-template-generation=1
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/kube-prometheus-1660560589-node-exporter
Containers:
  node-exporter:
    Image:      docker.io/bitnami/node-exporter:1.3.1-debian-11-r23
    Port:       9100/TCP
    Host Port:  9100/TCP
    Args:
      --path.procfs=/host/proc
      --path.sysfs=/host/sys
      --web.listen-address=0.0.0.0:9100
      --collector.filesystem.ignored-fs-types=^(autofs|binfmt_misc|cgroup|configfs|debugfs|devpts|devtmpfs|fusectl|hugetlbfs|mqueue|overlay|proc|procfs|pstore|rpc_pipefs|securityfs|sysfs|tracefs)$
      --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(dev|proc|sys|var/lib/docker/.+)($|/)
    Liveness:     http-get http://:metrics/ delay=120s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:    http-get http://:metrics/ delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /host/proc from proc (ro)
      /host/sys from sys (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-9fj8v (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  proc:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /proc
    HostPathType:
  sys:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /sys
    HostPathType:
  kube-api-access-9fj8v:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/network-unavailable:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule op=Exists
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                      From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                     ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  2m54s (x233 over 3h53m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports.
```

this is the netstat:

```
[root@k8smasterone ~]# netstat -plant |grep 9100
[root@k8smasterone ~]#
```

I also tried this to allow the pods running in master node by add this config:

```
tolerations:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
```

still did not fixed this problem.

Comment: What's  `netstat -plant |grep 9100` return on your node?

Comment: Your deployment definition has `hostNetwork: true`, meaning the pods spawned by this deployment will have access to your host node network resources.  by anychance you try to reboot your node to clean up the port ?

Comment: I could not reboot the host, this is the production node. @P....

Comment: What do your `kube-scheduler` logs say? Something like `k logs -n kube-system  kube-scheduler-k8s-master`

Comment: The issue you reported sounds like this https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/issues/728#issuecomment-1165317154

Comment: I also readed this issue, seem like a little different with mine.

Comment: @Dolphin Have you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure your pod with `hostNetwork: true`, the containers running in this pod can directly see the network interfaces of the host machine where the pod was started.

The container port will be exposed to the external network at :, the hostPort is the port requested by the user in the configuration `hostPort`.

To bypass your problem, you have two options:

- setting `hostNetwork: false`
- choose a different `hostPort` (it is better in the range 49152 to 65535)

Comment: but the 9100 was free in the host machine. @Hussein Awala

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error when I tried to deploy multiple ingress-nginx pods on the same node.

My solution is setting `hostNetwork: false` and specify ip address.

values.yaml

```
controller:
  service:
    loadBalancerIP: 10.13.35.138
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  electionID: ingress-nginx-private-test
  # hostNetwork: true
  replicaCount: 3
```